# How to check for whitespaces in CSV file?

Tags: php, validation, csv

Currently I am using `ctype_alnum` to check for alphanumeric type in csv file. But one of my data has white spaces between them and so `ctype_alnum` gives me false.

```
Example: ctype_alnum("Here is 23");
```

So  my question is how can I check for white spaces in string in php ?

Comment: ` if ((strtotime($data[11]) && strtotime($data[12]) && strtotime($data[16]))!==FALSE && ctype_digit($data[0]) && ctype_alnum($data[1]) && ctype_digit($data[2]) && ctype_alnum($data[3]) && ctype_alnum($data[4]) && ctype_alnum($data[5]) && ctype_alnum($data[6]) && ctype_alnum($data[7]) && ctype_alnum($data[8]) && ctype_alnum($data[9]) && ctype_digit($data[10]) && ctype_digit($data[13]) && ctype_alnum($data[14])) `

Comment: I am using in above pattern, so how can I do in a proper way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
// returns true if $str has a whitespace(space, tab, newline..) anywhere in it.
function has_whitespace($str) {
  return preg_match('/\s/',$str);
}
```

Or you can write you own function to check if a string contains only alphabets,digits,spaces:

```
// returns true if $str has nothing but alphabets,digits and spaces.
function is_alnumspace($str){
  return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i',$str);
}
```

Comment: `  if ((strtotime($data[11]) && strtotime($data[12]) && strtotime($data[16]))!==FALSE && ctype_digit($data[0]) && ctype_alnum($data[1]) 
  && ctype_digit($data[2]) && ctype_alnum($data[3]) && ctype_alnum($data[4]) && ctype_alnum($data[5]) && ctype_alnum($data[6]) 
  && ctype_alnum($data[7]) && ctype_alnum($data[8]) && ctype_alnum($data[9]) && ctype_digit($data[10]) && ctype_digit($data[13]) && ctype_alnum($data[14]))
`

Comment: I am using in above pattern, so how can I do in a proper way ?

Comment: @Rachel: I have updated my answer with a new function is_alnumspace(). If you were using ctype_alnum() before and want to allow spaces as well you can use that function.

Comment: I do not want to write new function, right now am using builtin function of php and so do we another similar kind of function to check white spaces

Comment: @Rachel: I'm not aware of any existing library function that check for spaces.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to check if a string consists of a letter (a-z) ignoring case (A-Z) or horizontal white space (space(0x20) and tab(0x09))? That would be:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z\h]+$/i', $string)) {
```